# GLTF export with animation does not cycle cleanly

Tags: animation

I have made a infinitely-rotating cube following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0FifixGets). I exported it as GLTF 2.0 file (from File menu). But when I load it in the [GLTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/), its animation *snaps* regularly - after certain frames - instead of repeating smoothly.

I have made a GIF demo of the situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAnkH.jpg (expected behavior is in blender and actual behavior is in firefox)

This is my graph editor:

[image]

How to fix this issue? I want to be able to load this GLTF into threejs and reuse the animation.

Comment: have you tried any other file formats?

Comment: @Aster17 Sorry, even if I can export them, I do not know how to view them outside of Blender. Also, I really do need GLTF format only regardless.

Comment: You could do this, import it as a .fbx and then convert it to GLTF format using an online converter like: http://www.swiftconverter.com/convert_3d